# Mongoose web server file stream API

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, mongoose, streaming

I am writing an API for my mongoose http server(`https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose`) to download a file from the system's disk.

I have a vanilla way of doing it by reading the file fully and returning the contents in the json response.

But I am looking for a directly streaming from the disk or some download the file kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

See mg_http_serve_file()

```c
 static void ev_handler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *ev_data) {
   switch (ev) {
     case MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST: {
       struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data;
       mg_http_serve_file(nc, hm, "file.txt",
                          mg_mk_str("text/plain"), mg_mk_str(""));
       break;
     }
     ...
   }
 }
```